# How to ensure that properties for Asp .net controls are set

Tags: c#, webforms

When i build my user controls, i want to make sure that users should set some of the properties in their code when they use my control. For example, lets say i build a customer user control that would be used by other developers in my team. Some of the properties that i have exposed are: `CustomerId`, `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address1`, `City`, `State` and `ZipCode`. I want to make sure that any consumer of my control sets `CustomerId` and if he/she forgets to set that property they should get some kind of error. Solution that would result in Compile time error in case `CustomerId` property is not set would be helpful.

Comment: `asp.net webforms` or `asp.net mvc`, or other?

Comment: also, for the sake of searching, the keyword you want to search for is `validation`

Answer (score 0):

after a quick search I've come up with the following resource:

http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_refvalidationcontrols.asp

here's an example of using the required validator

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form runat="server">
    Name: <asp:TextBox id="name" runat="server" />
    <br>
    Age: <asp:TextBox id="age" runat="server" />
    <br><br>
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Submit" />
    <br><br>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator
    ControlToValidate="name"
    Text="The name field is required!"
    runat="server" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

[here's the source of the example](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/showasp.asp?filename=demo_reqfieldvalidator)

Comment: This solution is ideal for the properties that are displayed as form elements. Like "firstname", "lastname". I am trying to solve problem for properties that are core to working of my asp .net webcontrols and are not rendered as form elements. Like in my example, CustomerId. So whenever user fails to set customerId property either intentionally or by an accident, system should help user either during compilation or control initialization.